# Linux Mint Cinnamon CSS theme misbehaving

Tags: css, linux-mint

I am trying to create a cinnamon CSS theme, but I'm having a very strange issue.

As you can see below, I have set `.menu-application-button:hover` and `.menu-application-button-selected`'s backgound-colour attribute to `#3478db`.

This works fine except when a scrollbar is present, where the background appears white. This is bizarre, as I have not set anything to white in the menu code at all. I have tried using `!important` but the problem still persists.

Is this just a silly mistake done by me, or a bug in cinnamon? And if it is a mistake how can I fix it?

here's the menu code:

```
/* ===================================================================
* Menu (menu.js)
* ===================================================================*/
.menu-favorites-box {
width: 50px;
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #aaa;
border-radius: 3px;
background-color: rgba(85,85,85,0.1);
transition-duration: 100;
}
.menu-favorites-button {
padding: 10px;
}
.menu-favorites-button:hover {
padding: 10px 4px 10px 16px;
}
.menu-help-button {
padding-top: 2px;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
}
.menu-help-button:hover {
    color: white;
background-gradient-direction: vertical;
background-gradient-start: rgba(255,255,255,0.12);
background-gradient-end: rgba(255,255,255,0.06);
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.12);
border-radius: 3px;

}
.menu-places-box {
padding: 10px;
}
.menu-places-button {
padding: 10px;
}
.menu-categories-box {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.menu-applications-box {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.menu-application-button {
height: 36px;
padding: 0px 7px;
}
.menu-application-button:hover,
.menu-application-button-selected {
height: 36px;
padding: 0px 7px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    background-color: #3478db;
    border-color: #3374D4;
}
.menu-application-button-label:ltr {
padding-left: 5px;
}
.menu-application-button-label:rtl {
padding-right: 5px;
}
.menu-category-button {
height: 36px;
padding: 0px 7px;
}
.menu-category-button-greyed {
height: 36px;
padding: 0px 7px;
color: #aaa;
}
.menu-category-button-selected {
height: 36px;
padding: 0px 7px;
    background-color: #3478db;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    border-color: #3374D4;
}
.menu-category-button-label:ltr {
padding-left: 5px;
}
.menu-category-button-label:rtl {
padding-right: 5px;
}
/* Name and description of the currently hovered item in the menu
* This appears on the bottom right hand corner of the menu*/
.menu-selected-app-box {
padding-right: 30px;
padding-left: 28px;
text-align: right;
}
.menu-selected-app-title {
font-weight: bold;
color: #4784de;
}
.menu-selected-app-description {
max-width: 150px;
color: #333;
}
.menu-search-box:ltr {
padding-left: 15px;
}
.menu-search-box:rtl {
padding-right: 15px;
}
#menu-search-entry {
border-image: url("entry.png") 5;
color: #333;
    caret-color: #333;
    font-size: 12pt;
    caret-size: 1px;
    selected-color: white;
    selection-background-color: #4784de;
    padding: 0px 8px;
width: 15em;
height: 30px;
}
.menu-search-entry-icon {
icon-size: 1em;
color: #333;
}

.menu-context-menu {
}
```

the full code, if needed, is available at http://pastebin.com/yTCF0b9f.

Comment: `As you can see below` Actually, I can't. There's no HTML markup here, nor at pastebin link.

Comment: cinnamon has no html, as such. It's a UI for linux, themed with css. I would provide screenshots but it won't let me while the menu is active.

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad. It should be related to Linux mint. I'm an Ubuntu guy.

Comment: @HashemQolami no problem, changed the tag so it's more obvious.